# Combinatorial proof with binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I need to prove this with combinatorial arguments. I don't know how to start.

$$
\sum_{j = r}^{n + r - k}{j - 1 \choose r - 1}{n - j \choose k - r} 
=
{n \choose k}\,,
\qquad\qquad 1\ \leq\ r\ \leq\  k\ \leq\  n
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the right hand side, I need to choose $k$ integers from the set $\{1,\ldots, n\}$.  On the left hand side:  for each possible $j$,  $r\leq j\leq n+r-k$, I make sure that the $r$-th smallest number chosen is $j$, then choose $r-1$ numbers from the $j-1$ smaller ones and $k-r$ numbers from the $n-j$ larger ones.

Answer (score 1):

The way to choose $k$ elements among $n$ elements is equal to choose $r-1$ elements at first, and choose $k-r$ elements at second, and choose one element at last.

Comment: Where do you choose the last element?